# Flutter how to change the pivotZ of rotation in Matrix4

Tags: flutter, dart

I m rotating some shape for example Rect with the matrix4 in Z-axis like this

```
 Matrix4.identity()
       ..rotateZ(.5);
```

but it is rotating the Rect from the top of the bounds how could I change it to center of the Rect

Comment: you need to translate it before and after rotation - something like here https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/61479

Comment: but actually it is much easier to use that [_rotate](https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/blob/master/lib/matrix_gesture_detector.dart#L206) function

Comment: @pskink yes thank you I used the code in the _rotate method and it works very well